# NextJS - all routes redirect to index

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm sure this is something simple that I'm overlooking, but I haven't found any information about such a problem online.  I have a fairly simple NextJS project with a folder structure as follows:

```
├── pages
|  ├── index.js
|  ├── _app.tsx
|  └── hello.tsx
```

Each file has respective CSS, but I didn't add it for simplicity.  I've written the bulk of my website in `_app.tsx`, and added `hello.tsx` to test page routing. From my understanding, if I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/hello`, I should see the page written in `hello.tsx`.  Instead, even though the address would indicate otherwise, the page defined in `_app.tsx` shows.  What am I missing here?

`hello.tsx` is as follows:

```
export default function hello() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
  }
```

`_app.tsx` is as follows:

```
import './App.css';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Tiles from '../components/tiles';
 
function App() {
  return (
    <some basic jsx/>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for any help.  I'm sure the answer is plain as day, but I haven't been able to get it.

Comment: can you share `_app.tsx` code

Comment: Sure, here it is:
https://pastebin.com/PtLVMRx8

Comment: Thats not correct. it should be `function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}`

Comment: My bad.  I added that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have added it above.

Answer (score 0):

I had `index.js` and `_app.js` completely wrong and was returning the homepage in `_app` instead of `index`.  If you are having a similar issue you might try reconfiguring them to stock and then working from there.